# Codeigniter: Accepting Space and Symbols for Validation with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, validation

I have a form that need to be validate, but I'm having hard time to figure out how validate using JQuery especially when JQuery change `space` into `%20` AND not accepting any symbols such as `@,$,!`, take a look at screenshot below

> **ERROR WITH SYMBOLS**
>       [image]

It's says that the URI you input has disallowed characters

> **SPACE**
>
> And then for `space` input it changes the value and adding `%20` [image]
>   of course `Firhal%20Faisal` is not in data base there's only `Firhan Faisal`

how can i manage to solve those 2 problems that i have?below are my javascript validation form for `name` that seems change `space` input into `%20`, and for email it's basically the same

> **JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#nama").bind("keyup change", function(){
    var nama = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'cekData/mahasiswa/nama_mahasiswa/'+nama,
        data:{send:true},
        success:function(data){
            if(data==1){
                $("#reportNama").text("");
                 $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled','');
                 $("#username").prop("disabled", '');
                 $("#password").prop("disabled", '');
                 $("#nim").prop("disabled", '');
                 $("#email").prop("disabled", '');
                 $("#telepon").prop("disabled", '');
            }else{
                $("#reportNama").text("*nama sudah ada");
                 $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);
                 $("#username").prop("disabled", true);
                 $("#password").prop("disabled", true);
                 $("#nim").prop("disabled", true);
                 $("#email").prop("disabled", true);
                 $("#telepon").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

> **CONTROLLER**

```
public function cekData($table,$field, $data){
    $match = $this->MDosen->read($table,array($field=>$data), null, null);
    if($match->num_rows() > 0){
        $report = 2;
    }else{
        $report = 1;
    }
    echo $report;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the value using GET or POST parameters:

> **JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'cekData/mahasiswa/nama_mahasiswa/',
    data:{send:true, value: nama},
    success:function(data){
        ...
    }
});
```

> **Controller**

```
public function cekData($table,$field){
    $data = $this->input->get('value');
    $match = $this->MDosen->read($table,array($field=>$data), null, null);
    if($match->num_rows() > 0){
        $report = 2;
    }else{
        $report = 1;
    }
    echo $report;
}
```

Comment: well it's work well for space, but when use symbol it didn't work, like when validate email `tes@gmail.com` the url send data like this `tes%40gmail.com` and error that said `dissalowed characters, any idea?

Comment: @MirzaChilman the error appears when the symbol is passed in URL or as a key of a GET/POST parameter, so you might need to double check what you do not do that.